# What should I do with this?

Tags: publishing, citations

So like, I received a message from "Author Liaison Representative" in Wattpad.

The thing said:

*Hello Mimiko-nyan,
My name is Tika. I'm an Author Liaison representative, representing W e b n o v e l.
I've read the initial chapters and I feel that your novel showcases your capabilities as a writer thus, I would like to invite you to publish on our platform W e b n o v e l. You may find our App on Appstore or Google Play, which has over tens of millions installations.
We would like to offer a non-exclusive contract for your novels currently on the site, this way, you can keep the novel on the site but at the same time also help you tap on the large reader base of on our platform with over 60 million unique user views, making it a win-win situation.
Please feel free to reach out to me with regards to this, we want to understand your needs first and foremost as an author to help you reach the target market you want to hit.
If you want to reach out personally, You can contact me at：
Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/WebnovelEditors
Facebook Messenger: WebnovelEditors (There should be a space between two words)
Instagram: WebnovelEditors (There should be a space between two words)
Discord: Tika#1808
Email: editorwn.tika@gmail.com*

I haven't answered this yet 'cause I feel like something's wrong. When I checked my stories, I don't think this person even read it because it had the same reads when I checked yesterday. (**I have a habit to check**)

I don't know whether I should give a message or ignore it. Please tell me what you think! Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Got a message from an Author Liaison representative representing Webnovel about the story I wrote. Any advice?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/52295/got-a-message-from-an-author-liaison-representative-representing-webnovel-about)

Comment: We get questions about this pretty frequently. It's a well-known scam; just ignore it.